# I'm creating a .csv file using fputcsv() and I would like to use AddAttachment() in PHPMailer to send it off automatically

Tags: php, csv, phpmailer

I've edited the original post, hopefully this is more to the point.  I would like to drop the .csv file created by fputcsv() and drop it into AddAttachment and send off.  Or, if you know how to take the .csv file created and send it to a directory on the server that would be fine too.  I think the most direct question is how do I take the results of fputcsv() and drop it into AddAttachments?  Do I use temp file?

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

        $csvoutput = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        $row = getRow($result3);
        $headers = array_keys($row);
        fputcsv($csvoutput, $headers);
            
               while ($row = getRow($result3)) {
    
                    fputcsv($csvoutput, $row);
    
                }

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "smtp.website.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Username   = $email_user;
$mail->Password   = $email_pass;
$mail->SetFrom("example@example.com", "Ex");
$mail->AddAddress("example@example.com", "Ex");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Subject    = "Example";
$mail->Body       = "Example";
$result = $mail->Send();



fclose($csvoutput);
exit;
```

Do I need the headers() if I'm not downloading it to the page?

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
```

Also, I know this needs to be changed:

```
$csvoutput = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

Please be as detailed as possible, I am unfamiliar with working with files and I couldnt find a tutorial specific to this.

Comment: If you're wondering why something doesn't work, your first step should be to [read the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment) rather than posting here. You'll get an instant, accurate response then. This might lead you to the function that you should be using, [`addStringAttachment`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read back from php://output. Save the CSV to a temp file:

```
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'my_script_');
$csvoutput = fopen($filename, 'w');
```

And then reference that file's path in the AddAttachment() call:

```
$mail->addAttachment($filename);
unlink($filename);
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to mess with temp files, you can use output buffering to capture standard out. (Since fputcsv() can't output directly to string.)

```
ob_start();
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
while (...) {
    fputcsv(...);
}
fclose($fp);
$csv_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$mail->addStringAttachment($csv_string,"file_name.csv");
```

Update:

You're probably doing something like this:

```
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'my_script.csv');
```

Which gives you `/tmp/my_script.csvPFj1Lw`

You want to do something like this:

```
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'my_script_') . '.csv';
```

Which gives you `/tmp/my_script_H5GVJp.csv`

The reason you want the random characters there is to avoid collisions in case you have more than one instance of the script running at the same time.

Comment: I think its close to working, from your first suggestion.  It does append some weird string at the end of .csv like file.csvA2M5sS how would I get rid of the A2M5sS part?

Comment: That works well thank you!  I am in a situation where I need to send a strict filename to another company that processes the .csv file.  For example i would need to send it as file.csv instead of fileLZNuGN.csv.  Would I use trim() or str_replace to get rid of those random characters?

Comment: No, just take out the call to `tempnam()` and use someting like `$filename = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/file.csv';` Note however this opens up the possibility of problems when more than one person requests the file at the same time.

Comment: you can replace `$csv_string = ob_get_contents();`with`$csv_string = ob_end_clean();`

Answer (score 2):

If your wanting to merge all three pieces of code plus have the PHP Mailer to send the attachment you can use the below code:

```
if ($db->connect_error) {
    $error = $db->connect_error;
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT pick_city, pick_state, delivery_city, delivery_state, trailer_type, pick_date, load_type, length, weight, offering, special_instructions, contact_name, contact_phone FROM exampleTable WHERE urgency <> 'Booked' AND urgency <> 'Quote' AND urgency <> 'Hold'";
    $result3 = $db->query($sql);
    if ($db->error) {
        $error = $db->error;
    }
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=filename.csv');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    $csvoutput = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $row = getRow($result3);
    $headers = array_keys($row);
    fputcsv($csvoutput, $headers);
    fputcsv($csvoutput, $row);
    while ($row = getRow($result3)) {
        fputcsv($csvoutput, $row);
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['submit_email'])){
        $message = $_POST['email'];
        $active_unique = $_POST['active_unique'];
        $hid_id = $_POST['hid_id'];
        $hid_email = $_POST['hid_email'];

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.website.com";
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Username   = $email_user;
        $mail->Password   = $email_pass;
        $mail->SetFrom($email_user, ucfirst($company) . " Quote System");
        $mail->AddReplyTo($userEmail, $userSesh);
        $mail->AddAddress("example@example.com", "Name");
        $mail->AddBCC("example@example.com", "Name");
        $mail->AddStringAttachment(file_get_contents('php://output'));
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->Subject    = "Please Review the Following Load";
        $mail->Body       = $message;

        $result = $mail->Send();
    }
    function getRow($result3) {
        return $result3->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
```

If you simply need to add attachment only, change:

```
$mail->AddAttachment( *I want to drop in the csv file* );
```

to:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment(file_get_contents('php://output'));
```

Comment: I edited my post to try and implement what you said.

Comment: This won't work. `addAttachment` only works with file paths. If you want to pass in a string, you need to use `addStringAttachment` instead.

Comment: I want to add the excel .csv file that is created, into an attachment.  Do I need to send the .csv file to the server first then pull it out and use AddAttachments?